# gRPC context.interceptCall() and SimpleForwardingServerCallListener

Tags: threadpool, grpc, grpc-java

1. Can someone explain or point me into the right direction where I can understand when to use ForwardingServerCallListener.SimpleForwardingServerCallListener or Contexts.interceptCall in gRPC intercept call on the server side.
2. In REST a thread gets associated with a request and does the same happen in gRPC too or when a request gets delegated a new thread is created?

Comment: For 2nd point you can look into : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47505022/does-grpc-server-spin-up-a-new-thread-for-each-request